How to merge Extended partition to Primary partition without loosing data in Ubuntu
I have VM(Ubuntu 22.04 OS) in ESXi VMWare. I want to merge extended partition(/dev/sda2) to Primary partition(/dev/sda5) without loosing the data.
Can someone please help me on this with the steps or share some reference link as I want to take any risk coz it is having PROD data? Thank you.

cfdisk command output -

Getting below error when I tried to fix using link - Resize an extended partition with free space
Error - The size of this disk is 4 TiB (4398046511104 bytes). DOS partition table format cannot be used on drives for volumes larger than 2199023255040 bytes for 512-byte sectors. Use GUID partition table format (GPT).

Your real issue is using MBR(msdos) partitioning on a drive over 2TB. You need to be using gpt as MBR does not support drives over 2TB. MBR was designed in the 1980s when MB was large and GB was only for mainframes. So set max at 2TB to last forever. But since 2012 Microsoft has required vendors to install with UEFI and gpt partitioning. Linux supported gpt several years before that. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html  if you convert with other tools, entire drive is erased.
